# Rails 4 Validation Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following Validation rules for my model

```
validates :name, 
        presence: {:message => "Please enter a group name."},  
        uniqueness: {:message => "Group name already exisits."}, 
        length: {:minimum => 2, :message => "Group name should be min. 2 characters"}
```

When i keep the filed empty and submit it validates right but shows both the following messages

```
2 errors prohibited this user_group from being saved:

    Name Please enter a group name.
    Name Group name should be min. 2 characters
```

Since the error is for the same field i would like to only show the first error `Please enter a group name` and only if the user enters less than two characters i would like to display the second error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `allow_blank` here

```
length: {:minimum => 2, :message => "Group name should be min. 2 characters", :allow_blank => true}
```

Comment: am talking about the validation error. if i dont fill the form and submit it should only show please enter the name. not show the second validation rule of length

Comment: thanks. so adding this it will only show the first one or how does the ordering work?

Comment: Setting `allow_blank` to true for `length` will skip this validation when the field is left blank, but as you have defined validation for `presence`, it will come to play and display the validation errors on screen